# Non-existing path in libtiff

Tags: python, enthought, canopy, bitarray

I'm trying to install pylibtiff (under Enthought Canopy), and receiving the following trace:
non-existing path in 'libtiff':

```
'bitarray-0.3.5-numpy/bitarray'
Warning: Assuming default configuration (bitarray-0.3.5-numpy/bitarray/{setup_bitarray,setup}.py was not found)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 96, in <module>
    configuration = configuration,
  File "/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 66, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('libtiff')
  File "/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "libtiff/setup.py", line 18, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('bitarray', bitarray_path)
  File "/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 928, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level+1)
  File "/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 707, in __init__
    raise ValueError("%r is not a directory" % (package_path,))
ValueError: 'bitarray-0.3.5-numpy/bitarray' is not a directory
```

What is this?  What does it mean?

EDIT: Checked out and installed latest version from SVN, then looked in Ubuntu 14.04 Software Center.  When doing `from libtiff import *`, I'm getting `ImportError: No module named libtiff`.  It seems when starting Canopy Python, the version is 2.7.6.  Using locate libtiff.so shows that it's in the ~/Python2.7.8 directory.  Is there a version mismatch?

Comment: Exactly what did you do, previous to this traceback?

Comment: 1. Deleted my ~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User, ~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System, and ~/canopy directories, and removed $PATH references to Canopy in ~/.bashrc.
2. Restarted Canopy, and let files get recreated.
3. Reinstalled opencv, and updated all of my installed packages through package manager.
4. Changed my .matplotlibrc file to use Qt4Agg as the backend
5. To install pylibtiff:
`svn checkout http://pylibtiff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ pylibtiff-svn`
    `cd pylibtiff-svn`
    `python setup.py install`

Comment: I should note deletions were per [this article.](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy)

Comment: On the pylibtiff installation: output of `which python`?

Comment: Are you heeding: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line ?

Comment: `which python` output: `/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python`
Re: heeding the linked article: I have not installed setuptools.  I'm following the README associated with pylibtiff for installation instructions.  Other external package installs have seemed to work properly.